# How to download embedded content-id images from outlook using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to download embedded images in outlook using selenium python. I have tried to run the following code to download such images but it failed. The code can be used to download attachments but not embedded images. Anyone has any ideas how to download images to folder in python? Thanks so much.

The code i used was (it only works for attached images):

```
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    src = img.get_attribute('src')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, f"img {i}.png")
```

Comment: What API are you using to access the messages? In OOM yo ucan loop through message attachments (`Message.Attachments`) and save one attachment at a time using `Attachment.SaveAsFile`.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, thanks for your comment. I am accessing it just through chrome browser. The reason i don't want to use outlook python package is that i want to avoid the firewall set by my company. So i went with the selenium method. Do you perhaps know how to download content-id images through selenium. Thanks. :)